# Where can I find Standard Node (and IDs) in the OPC UA Specification?

Tags: opc-ua, node-opcua

i am creating a simple OPC UA Client. I need to know where i can find a document with the list of all standard nodes and their IDs.

Thank you
Joshwa

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the version of UA, but:

https://opcfoundation.org/UA/schemas/1.02/NodeIds.csv
https://opcfoundation.org/UA/schemas/1.03/NodeIds.csv
https://opcfoundation.org/UA/schemas/1.04/NodeIds.csv

Most Stacks will have some kind of static enumeration available to reference as well.

For example, Eclipse Milo lists them [here](https://github.com/eclipse/milo/blob/master/opc-ua-stack/stack-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/stack/core/Identifiers.java), and [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard/master/Stack/Opc.Ua.Core/Stack/Generated/Opc.Ua.Constants.cs) are the ones from .NET reference implementation.

Comment: and for node-opcua , Ids are predefined here : https://github.com/node-opcua/node-opcua/blob/master/packages/node-opcua-constants/src/opcua_node_ids.js